# Mbtiles generation with tippecanoe on a mixed geojson feature file

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, ogr2ogr, tippecanoe

I have a bunch of geojson files that I want to use to create a .mbtiles file, these geojson files were made by using ogr2ogr on a .osm.pbf file.

Though these files seemed to have mixed features within them, e.g. the linestring.geojson file has waterways and highways feature types, and the layer this generates is name after the file not the individual feature types.

How would I go about formatting this or using tippecanoe to separate these features into separate layers so then I could use this on a tileserver.

My only thought on how this could be done would be to separate the file myself but this would be extremely time consuming even on the smallest of .osm.pbf files.

I want to be able to generate the .mbtiles file like this, so then I could use it in turn with map box.